# Connection between the infinity operation norm and Gershgorin circles

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Gershgorin circle section of my textbook, there was the following statement:

> The infinity operation norm of $A$ (meaning $\|A\|_{op}^{\infty}$), is equal to the largest distance from the $(0,0)$ to the $(x,y)$  where $(x,y)$ is a point of one of the gershgorin circles.

*I think the infinity norm is also called the maximum norm.*

For example:

[image]

Then you get $\|A\|_{op}^{\infty}=12.5$.

I'm trying to prove this theorem but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. Also, is it true for circles that their center is not located on the Real axis? So, Is there a closed form for calculating $\|A\|_{op}^{\infty}$ then?

Comment: Are you aware that 
$$
\|A\|^\infty_{\text{op}} = \max_{i=1,\dots,n} \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|?
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the disc corrosponding to the $i$th row
$$\mathbb{D}_i = \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C}:\ |z-a_{ii}|\leq \sum_{j\neq i} |a_{ij}| \right \}$$
To get as far from the origin on it, we should "go away" from it, in the same line as $a_{ii}$ points to. More formally, for any $z$ within the disc from the triangle inequality
$$|z| \leq |z-a_{ii}| + |a_{ii}| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$$
And this upper bound is achieved when $z-a_{ii}$ and $a_{ii}$ are co-linear as vectors (meaning, they're a real scaling of each other), and $z$ is on the boundary.

If so, then the farthest we can get from the origin using any disc is $\text{max}_i  \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|$ which is exactly $\left \| A \right \|_\infty$. This is valid regardless where the circles are located, perhaps is just easier to see in that case where the diagonal is real, since we are looking at the "rightmost" or "leftmost" tip.